# FCM IOS notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

The code is working fine when I try to send notification on android but it does not work for IOS notification. Getting the below error:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "messaging/internal-error",
        "message": "An internal error has occurred. Please retry the request."
      }
    }
  ],
  "canonicalRegistrationTokenCount": 0,
  "failureCount": 1,
  "successCount": 0,
  "multicastId": 8118740071861272000
}
```

This is my code sample, please take a look and help me to resolve the issue.
also, I get a notification when I try to send notification from cloud messages console.

```
    return await admin.messaging()
          .sendToDevice(deviceToken, {
   data: {
       title: 'Test Fcm',
       body: 'tesing fmc body',
       content_available: 'true',
       priority: 'high',
       action_type: 'TEST'
     },
     notification: {
       title: 'Test Fcm',
       body: 'tesing fmc body',
       content_available: 'true',
       priority: 'high'
     }
   }
  , {
   priority: "high",
   timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
   contentAvailable:true,
}).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            
          })
```

Comment: Did you upload your APNS authentication keys to the Firebase Console?  Make sure you have followed the [Configure APNS with FCM guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs) and nothing is wrong from that side.

Comment: yes, I have uploaded the APNS authentication keys. it was working fine suddenly it's throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

i have encount 2 days ago this issue.

just remove 'content_available' from 'notification', it's working.

example for your json =>

```
{
   data: {
       title: 'Test Fcm',
       body: 'tesing fmc body',
       content_available: 'true',
       priority: 'high',
       action_type: 'TEST'
     },
     notification: {
       title: 'Test Fcm',
       body: 'tesing fmc body',
       => content_available: 'true', // remove this
       priority: 'high'
     }
}
```

regards.